How do I get a font to stay the same when someone runs my tkinter exe on their computer?
I'm trying to create a GUI standalone application using tkinter. There is a font dependency issue while running the script. Getting `

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'add_file'

Below is the code and error screenshot.
import pyglet,tkinter

if __name__ == "__main__":

pyglet.font.add_file('fonts/Cera-Round-Bold.ttf')

root = tkinter.Tk()
MyLabel = tkinter.Label(root,text="test",font=('Cera Round Variable DEMO',25))
MyLabel.pack()
root.mainloop()

Error screenshot
Font Style/Name
Tried using pyglet module.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots (how to format code in posts). Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors? http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Please fix the code indentation. The body of the if statement needs to be indented.

Code indentation is already there in the error screenshot. While posting the code for some reason it didn't take the indentation. Even if I indent, I get the error AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'add_file'. Could you please look at the error screenshot and help me out?

The error doesn't have anything to do with the indentation. The problem is simply that pyglet.font is set to None. I don't know enough about Pyglet to explain what you need to do to fix that.

BTW, the code in the screenshot doesn't have the if statement. Why is that in the text version of the code?

I'm guessing you've seen this answer and commenters report issues with non-Windows operating systems. Can you [edit] your question to include operating system details. Also there's a mismatch between the Font name in the screenshot and the name you supply to tkinter.Label(…).
